# How to configure gitlab omnibus installation to use mysql instead of postgresql

Tags: linux, gitlab, omnibus

I'm trying to install gitlab (omnibus) latest version on ubuntu 18.04. And my earlier version is gitlab (source) is using mysql. I want to manually copy the tables from the old version and hence want this installation this to use mysql. Any procedure for the same or links is greatly helpful.

EDIT:

jrtapsell's answer says -

> MySQL in Omnibus GitLab package is only supported in GitLab Enterprise
>   Edition Starter and Premium. The MySQL server itself is not shipped
>   with Omnibus, you will have to install it on your own or use an
>   existing one. Omnibus ships only the MySQL client.

Is there any procedure on how to "you will have to install it on your own" as mentioned in the docs and configure gitlab to use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Is it possible to use GitLab community with MySQL

It is no longer possible to use MySQL with GitLab community edition

> MySQL in Omnibus GitLab package is only supported in GitLab Enterprise Edition Starter and Premium. The MySQL server itself is not shipped with Omnibus, you will have to install it on your own or use an existing one. Omnibus ships only the MySQL client.

[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html#using-a-mysql-database-management-server-enterprise-edition-only)

## How can I upgrade my server

There are instructions available [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/mysql_to_postgresql.md) which cover how to move the data from an existing MySQL database into a new PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Thats exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Hey, it says "you will have to install it on your own or use an existing one. Any idea how to go about that ?"

Comment: It means you'll need to setup the MySQL server yourself, but that only works with the enterprise version of gitlab

Comment: It doesn't say that the mysql wont work with CE version right. It just doesn't get packed with the omnibus ce.